# Проверка группы в списке

Tags: java, android, if

Пытаюсь написать проверку для конкретной группы в списке:

```
 for(Groupss g :jsonResponse.getForm().getmGroupss()) {
                if(g.getmControls().get(0).getTitle().equals("type")) {
                    mList.add(g);
                }
```

Выбивает следующую ошибку:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                              Process: com.comp.secondproject, PID: 11587
>                                                                              java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

И указывает на 2-ую строку в коде.

Comment: Значит структура "jsonResponse" пустая

Comment: трудно сказать , что возвращает getmControls(). Если он возвращает Collection то проверьте сперва на пустоту а затем уже доставайте элемент с индексом 0

Comment: @Valera Kvip нет, т.к. изначально была такая запись :
mList.addAll(jsonResponse.getForm().getmGroupss());
и получал отлично элементы.

Comment: Текст ошибки однозначно указывает на то, что вы пытаетесь обратиться к первому элементу пустой коллекции, другого тут быть не может. Почему она пустая можете понять только вы.

Comment: @temq почему изначально тогда всё работало? 
Или может что то посоветуете подправить в коде? так как я не очень понимаю почему так происходит.

Comment: Тут не подскажешь. Ищите, где у вас заполняется коллекция `tmControls`, к которой идет обращение. Чтобы избежать ошибки, добавьте в условие `if` вначале:  `null!= g.getmControls() && !g.getmControls().isEmpty()`(т.е. проверку на не-пустубю коллекцию)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

поменяйте ваше условие на

```
if(g.getmControls() != null && g.getmControls().size() > 0 && "type".equals(g.getmControls().get(0).getTitle()))
```

Comment: Ошибка пропала, но элементы списка не отображаются в моём recyclerView(пустой)

Comment: @VadimMorozov, видимо, не один из элементов не проходит это условие. Не у одного в g.getmControls().get(0).getTitle() нету "type"

Comment: должны быть, раньше же отображались. Или я опять "криво" не туда смотрю?)

Comment: а если я хочу к примеру удалить элемент из списка? то как можно будет определить этот элемент? что потом написать что то подобное:
Iterator<Object> i = objs.iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
   Object o = i.next();
    i.remove();

Comment: @VadimMorozov,  в вашем предыдущем вопросе вы сравнивали не с `"type"`. `switch (mList.get(position).getmControls().get(0).getTitle()){
        case "textbox_numeric":
            temp=0;
            break;
        case "drop_down_options":
            temp = 1;
            break;
        default:
            temp =1;
    }`

Comment: @VadimMorozov, вы сравнивали с `textbox_numeric` и `drop_down_options`

Comment: да, спасибо, уже разобрался. + Отдельное спасибо за толковое разъяснение в чате;)